# jQuery Find <li> with CSS Property

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to use `.find()` to find a list item with a css property?

I thought this might work, but apparently not:

```
$('#selector').find('li').css('font-family','Arial, sans-serif').addClass('class');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you are trying to select `li` elements with a `font-family` property of `Arial, sans-serif`. If that's right, you can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the matched set to those elements which pass the test:

```
$("#selector").find("li").filter(function() {
    return this.style.fontFamily === "Arial, sans-serif";
}).addClass("class");
```

What you currently have will apply the `font-family` rule you have specified to all `li` elements found by the call to `find`, and then apply the `class` to all of them as well.

**Edit**

As noted in the comments, the `style` property only takes into account inline CSS properties (those defined in a `style` attribute on the element). If that is not the case, you can use the jQuery `css` getter method:

```
$("#selector").find("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("fontFamily") === "Arial, sans-serif";
}).addClass("class");
```

Comment: `this.style.` means inline styles in the html elements while `jQuery.fn.css` uses `elem.currentStyle`/`window.getComputedStyle(elem)` which means the style can be retrieved even if it came from css. It's not too clear which one the OP wanted though.

Comment: @Esailija - Very true. Good point, thanks. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks James! I appreciate the help and explanation. I haven't used .filter() before, and may be using it more often. The second method worked for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#selector').find('li').filter(function (){return $(this).css('font-family')=='Arial'  || $(this).css('font-family')=='sans-serif'}).addClass('class');
```

Comment: I think the OP is after elements with a font-family value of "Arial, sans-serif", not either "Arial" or "sans-serif".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but not with `find()` alone, I'd suggest iterating through the `li` elements with `each()`, I think:

```
$('li').each(
    function(){
        if ($(this).css('font-family') == 'Arial' || $(this).css('font-family') == 'sans-serif') {
            $(this).addClass('class');
        });
```

Comment: I think the OP is after elements with a `font-family` value of "Arial, sans-serif", not either "Arial" or "sans-serif".

Comment: A valid point, certainly. But since your answer accomplishes that already, I'd not like to add essentially the same information again to my answer. It just feels like pretension to do so. So I leave this as an incomplete answer, covering a divergent assumption. But my thanks for the pointer. =)

Comment: Very true, and altogether more useful than simply changing your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find by inline css property you could try [css contain selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/):

```
$('#selector li[style|"Arial, sans-serif"]').addClass('class');
```

If you are looking by css property defined in css file, then you should locate the items using the filter define those li items in the external css file. Let's say suppose your css file has: `.myLI {font-family: Arial, sans-serif;}`, then you could type `$'(#selector li.myLI').addClass('class')`